# Getting Junk and special character while decoding string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am stuck with one problem.
When I try to decode string with **Base64** then its will return some special character in response. And if we try to use this string then app is crashed. Below is the code string which is get from decoding value.

```
64B´%4àîÈÝ%ZÌ%
´E@/vÀ6mÔ¶ÅªÜ
```

What I have to do to make it as normal string ?
Can anyone help me out of this problem ?

Comment: Maybe you could post your decoding code and an example of the encoded string.

Comment: did you try to decode string with ASCII rather than Base64?  if not try this once.         <YOUR STRING NAME> = [<YOUR STRING NAME> stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: check [this](http://agerson.net/base64-encode-and-decode-nsstring-cocoa) link

Comment: I was going to post answer, for 100,555. undelete it, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go this way

1. download Base64 files from [here](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip)
2. Pull out these two files (**NSData+Base64.h, NSData+Base64.m**)from downloaded folder and add to your project.
3. disable ARC for these newly added files (if you enable ARC in your project)
4. **#import "NSData+Base64.h"** into your file
5. use below two methods to acomplish your task

   *base64Encode*

   *base64Decode*

Here is the my code snip, how I did in my demo example

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize messageTextField;
@synthesize resultBase64Label;
@synthesize resultPlainTextLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)convertToBase64:(id)sender {
    
    //keypad go back
    [messageTextField resignFirstResponder];
    
    NSString *resultBase64String = [self base64Encode:messageTextField.text];
    resultBase64Label.text = resultBase64String;    
}

- (IBAction)convertToPlainText:(id)sender {
    
    NSString *resultPlainString = [self base64Decode:resultBase64Label.text];
    resultPlainTextLabel.text = resultPlainString;
}

//convert plain text o base64
- (NSString *)base64Encode:(NSString *)plainText
{
    NSData *plainTextData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainTextData base64EncodedString];
    return base64String;
}

//convert base64 to plain text
- (NSString *)base64Decode:(NSString *)base64String
{
    NSData *plainTextData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64String];
    NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainTextData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return plainText;
}

@end
```

and here is the result screen

[image]

Comment: will it convert encode special characters in string(textfield.text)?

Answer (score 1):

I have used below methods for base64 encoding/decoding...

```
- (NSString *)base64Encode:(NSString *)plainText
 {
    NSData *plainTextData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainTextData base64EncodedString];
    return base64String;
 }

- (NSString *)base64Decode:(NSString *)base64String
{
    NSData *plainTextData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64String];
    NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainTextData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return plainText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *bufferStr = @"64B´%4àîÈÝ%ZÌ%´E@/vÀ6mÔ¶ÅªÜ";
NSData *temp = [bufferStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *dst = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"converted: %@", dst);
```

Or use `encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`

Here is [official documentation refere it might be helpful for you.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-dataUsingEncoding_allowLossyConversion_)